# Custom object not storing all names

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, custom-object

I have this code in my gymInfo class:

```
public class gymInfo
{
   public gymArray getAllGymsByStars()
   {
        gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter gymsTableAdapter = new gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter();
        DataTable gymsDataTable = gymsTableAdapter.getAllGymsByStars();
        gymArray gymArray = new gymArray();

        foreach(DataRow row in gymsDataTable.Rows)
        {
            gymArray.name = row["name"].ToString();        
        }
        return gymArray;
    }
}
```

The `gymsDataTable` contains 20 rows of names, now I have made a custom class, here is the code:

```
public class gymArray
{
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Which I expected the `string name` to get populated with 20 names (as their is 20 rows in the datatable) however when I debug on line `return gymArray` it only shows the name of the last row rather than showing a whole custom array of names.

Does anyone understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how do you expect to store an array in a single variable.

Comment: `gymArray` is just a single string value, not an actual array of strings.

Comment: the class you are calling `gymArray` is in no way an array

Comment: gymArray is just an object, it is not list or array in simple words it is not an Enumerable.

Comment: I would recommend creating something like this 
at the class level 
`public static nameList = new List<string>` then populate it inside of your foreach loop using the `List<T>.Add()` method or create a `List<gymArray>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually created an array. You've got a single `gymArray` object, and you're just changing its name property repeatedly.

Also, you're not following [C# conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx) when naming things. Your code should be more like this:

```
public class GymInfo
{
   public List<Gym> GetAllGymsByStars()
   {
        gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter gymsTableAdapter = new gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter();
        DataTable gymsDataTable = gymsTableAdapter.getAllGymsByStars();    
        List<Gym> gyms = new List<Gym>();    
        foreach(DataRow row in gymsDataTable.Rows)
        {
            Gym gym = new Gym();
            gym.Name = row["name"].ToString();
            gyms.Add(gym);      
        }
        return gyms;
    }
}

public class Gym
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of a naming a single object an "array", I created a generic List of Gym objects and returned that from the `GetAllGymsByStars` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class gymArray
{
  public List<string> names { get; set; }
}

public gymArray getAllGymsByStars()
{
  gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter gymsTableAdapter = new gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter();
  DataTable gymsDataTable = gymsTableAdapter.getAllGymsByStars();
  gymArray gymArray = new gymArray();
  gymArray.names = new List<string>();

  foreach(DataRow row in gymsDataTable.Rows)
  {
     gymArray.names.Add(row["name"].ToString());        
  }
  return gymArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you expect to store all the names as you each time overwrite the `name` property in the foreach loop

The loop is just doing for you something like:

```
gymArray.name = "some name";
gymArray.name = "other name";
```

Which, I guess, you are totally aware that the last value of `name` will be `other name`. You either append to the last value with `+` operator which will result in a big string of names, or change the `name` property to some collection and add new names. Maybe `string` is not your preferred type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement as

`List<gymArray> gymArray = new List<gymArray>();`

and in the loop.

`gymArray.Add(new gymAray { name : row["name"].ToString() });`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are setting the property of the same object again and again.

Try this

```
public class gymInfo
{
   public gymArray[] getAllGymsByStars()
   {
       int count = 0;
        gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter gymsTableAdapter = new gymDataTableAdapters.gymsTableAdapter();
        DataTable gymsDataTable = gymsTableAdapter.getAllGymsByStars();
        gymArray[] gymArray = new gymArray[gymsDataTable.Rows.Count];

        foreach(DataRow row in gymsDataTable.Rows)
        {
            gymArray[count] = new gymArray();
            gymArray[count].name = row["name"].ToString();
            count++;
        }
        return gymArray;
    }
}
```